# What's the most optimal method of motor attachment for Horizontal Static Fire Tests?

Tags: rockets, testing, amateur-rocketry

I'm a college student new to rocketry, and am working on the horizontal test structure for a static fire test of our motors. 
The max thrust for the booster motor is about 6000 pounds, and the sustainer motor is about 3000 pounds.

My question was, what would be the most optimal method of attaching the motors to the structure?

Also, does anyone have any recommended sources for further personal research on static fire tests?

We're essentially looking to go with the structure of the attached picture: [image]

Dimensions: Large Horizontal: 108" Long, 26" Wide, 47" Height